# Computational complexity of chemical dynamics for biological studies

Tags: complexity, computational-chemistry

How many CPU cycle is required to simulate a complete human body from it's very initial stem cell using classical algorithms and also is it possible to use similar algorithms for simulating stem cells themselves from their very initial atoms?

How much computing these models will cost based on available hardwares today?

Answer (score 3):

The estimated number of cells in the human body is $3.72 \times 10^{13}$;<sup>1</sup> the estimated number of molecules in a single cell is about $10^{14}$.<sup>2</sup>

Given that the current peta-scale supercomputers need a full day to simulate the motion of $1.2\times 10^{7}$ particles over $49$ nanoseconds<sup>3</sup> -- and a simulation of the complexity you propose needs to keep track of much more than just the position! -- what you propose is completely infeasible with the technology that can realistically be expected to be available in the near and mid future.

---

<sub>1. [Bianconi E1, Piovesan A, Facchin F, Beraudi A, Casadei R, Frabetti F, Vitale L, Pelleri MC, Tassani S, Piva F, Perez-Amodio S, Strippoli P, Canaider S: An estimation of the number of cells in the human body. Ann Hum Biol. 2013 Nov-Dec;40(6):463-71](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23829164)</sub>

<sub>2. This number appears as a factoid on a number of websites and is often attributed to "a group of engineers from Washington University". No reference is given, and my brief search didn't turn up anything, either. As a ballpark estimate, it seems about right.</sub>

<sub>3. [Kutzner, C., Apostolov, R., Hess, B., & Grubmüller, H. (2014). Scaling of the GROMACS 4.6 molecular dynamics code on SuperMUC. In M. Bader, A. Bode, & H. J. Bungartz (Eds.), Parallel Computing: Accelerating Computational Science and Engineering (CSE) (pp. 722-730). Amsterdam: IOS Press](https://www.mpibpc.mpg.de/14613164/Kutzner_2014_ParCo-conf2013.pdf)</sub>